# Automatically taking thread dumps or heap dumps

Tags: visualvm, jmc

I'm trying to monitor a Java Application over a long period of time.

I want to automatically take a Thread dump or Heap Dump if number of threads or Heap exceeds some threshold.

Is this functionality available via VisualVM or Mission Control or other profiling tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start the JMX Console in Java Mission Control

Go to the Triggers tab and select trigger rule "Thread Count" or "Live Set". You can select threshold and action to take. If running JDK 8, I think you can invoke a diagnostic command, such as Thread.print. It's also possible to dump a Flight Recording, which contains thread dumps among many other things.